# How to select a range of numbers only between 10-15 in regex

Tags: regex

how would i accomplish this using regex?

Comment: post your attempts...

Answer (score 2):

```
^[1][0-5]$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD0sJ3/7